# android Dividing circle into N equal parts and know the coordinates of each dividing point

Tags: android, math, geometry

I have requirement that a circle should be divided into N equal parts based on number(2,3...n. But I want the coordinates of dividing points.

I have a circle whose `centre(x,y)` and `radius(150)` are known.

***Question:***

*Is there any formula which gives me the coordinates of dividing points as shown in figure. Can anyone please tell me the formula. I want to implement it in Java*.

***Circle image for refrence:***

[image]

Comment: x = x0 + sin(angle) * r, y = y0 + cos(angle) * r

Comment: How is that the formula not correct and it is used in every single answer here including the accepted one. Give a credit for the man

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to [convert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_coordinates#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates) between [polar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_coordinates) and [Cartesian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) coordinates. The angle you need is the angle between the (imaginary) vertical line that splits the circle in half and the line that connects the center with the circle's boundary. With this formula you can calculate the X and Y offsets from the center.

In your example image the first angle is 0, and the second one is 360/n. Each next is `i*(360/n)` where i is the index of the current line you need to draw. Applying this will give you the X and Y offsets in a clockwise order (and you can just add them to the X and Y coordinates of the center to find the coordinates of each point)

EDIT: some kind of pseudo-code:

```
//x0, y0 - center's coordinates
for(i = 1 to n)
{
    angle = i * (360/n);
    point.x = x0 + r * cos(angle);
    point.y = y0 + r * sin(angle);
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer..+1 form me...if u give me formula which returns the array with co ordinates..it would be appreciated...i will sure accept ur answer.I want to pass number which defines no of equal parts and return array with co ordinates..!

Comment: @Indiandroid You should be able to apply this to fit your needs without him having to adapt it for you.  If you can't do this on your own, you shouldn't be programming.

Comment: @stan0 sry for inconvenience.i haven’t time so i told u to make formula for me in java.. but i will sure try ur suggestion...and let u know.

Comment: @stan0 ur formula is perfect...soon i will accept ur answer..just i need to convert it into JAVA code and pass correct values....thanks.

Answer (score 24):

I have already accepted answer... the formula works perfectly.
Here is the solution coded in Java. It will help other developers.

```
    private int x[];  // Class variable
    private int y[];  // Class variable

    private void getPoints(int x0,int y0,int r,int noOfDividingPoints)
    {

        double angle = 0;

        x = new int[noOfDividingPoints];
        y = new int[noOfDividingPoints];

        for(int i = 0 ; i < noOfDividingPoints  ;i++)
        {
            angle = i * (360/noOfDividingPoints);

            x[i] = (int) (x0 + r * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)));
            y[i] = (int) (y0 + r * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)));

        }

        for(int i = 0 ; i < noOfDividingPoints  ;i++)
        {
            Log.v("x",""+i+": "+x[i]);
            Log.v("y",""+i+": "+y[i]);

        }
    }
```

Where x0 and y0 are co ordinates of circle's centre.and r is radius.

**In my case:**

**Input** x0 = 0 , y0 = 0 and r = 150 , noOfDividingPoints = 5

**output**

point1: (150,0)

point2: (46,142)

point3: (-121,88)

point4: (-121,-88)

point5: (46,-142)

Comment: the function does not provide accurate results always, like i want a circle to radius 100 with 5 noOfDividingPoints, when you are moving object on touch

Comment: @Syed Zahid Ali if you change the radius then points will also change...I have tested the formula for different points and it is working perfect.

Comment: I was having wrong results when I was selecting odd noOfDividingPoints