# Dividing circle into n equal parts to get coordinates of each dividing point

Tags: c++

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610350/android-dividing-circle-into-n-equal-parts-and-know-the-coordinates-of-each-divi) and I tried to implement it in C++, but the output is quite different. I have no idea what is wrong. 
The code I used:

```
double cordinate_print()
{
    int x, y;
    int number_of_chunks = 5;
    double angle=0;
    double x_p[5] ; // number of chunks 
    double y_p[5]; // number of chunks 
    //double x0, y0 = radious;
    double rad = 150;

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_chunks; i++)
    {
        angle = i * (360 / number_of_chunks);
        float degree = (angle * 180 / M_PI);
        x_p[i] = 0 + rad * cos(degree);
        y_p[i] = 0 + rad * sin(degree);
        //printf("x-> %d y-> %d \n", x_p[i], y_p[i]);
        cout << "x -> " << x_p[i] << "y -> " << y_p[i] << "\n";
    }

    //printing x and y values

    printf("\n \n");

    return 0;

}
```

Output

```
x -> 150 y -> 0
x -> -139.034 y -> -56.2983
x -> 107.74 y -> 104.365
x -> -60.559 y -> -137.232
x -> 4.77208 y -> 149.924
```

The correct output

```
(150,0)

(46,142)

(-121,88)

(-121,-88)

(46,-142)
```

Comment: Calling a variable "degrees" when it's actually an angle in radians is misleading to humans. The compiler doesn't care, though. Don't see the problem directly, but the points do appear to be on the circle - it's just that the angles are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with the conversion of degree into radian

```
float degree = (angle * 180 / M_PI);
```

The correct conversion formula is

```
float radian = (angle * M_PI / 180);
```

Also as mentioned in the comment use the good name to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Since your default angles are in degrees, you need to convert them to radians first before using `sin()` and `cos()`, then multiplying it to the radius.

```
double cordinate_print()
{
    int number_of_chunks = 5;
    double degrees = 0;                         // <-- correction
    double x_p[5]; // number of chunks 
    double y_p[5]; // number of chunks 
    double radius = 150;                        // <-- correction

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_chunks; i++)
    {
        degrees = i * (360 / number_of_chunks); // <-- correction
        float radian = (degrees * (M_PI / 180));  // <-- correction
        x_p[i] = radius * cos(radian);          // <-- correction
        y_p[i] = radius * sin(radian);          // <-- correction

        cout << "x -> " << x_p[i] << "y -> " << y_p[i] << "\n";
    }

    //printing x and y values
    printf("\n \n");

    return 0;
}
```